# Gparted not installable in Ubuntu 15.10 due to unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies, gparted

Gparted worked fine in Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 (I'm not sure about 15.04)) but I'm having trouble installing it in 15.10 from the software center. It gives the error: “Package dependencies cannot be resolved.”  I tried the following answer suggested in the forum posting “Gparted not working”:

> Try removing these packages gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol type in this command.
>
> > sudo apt-get remove gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol
>
> and then install ubuntu-desktop if it removes it.
>
> > sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 pavucontrol

But when I did this, I got the following error in the terminal:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> > gparted : libatkmm-1.6-1 (>= 2.22.1) but it is not installable
> >
> > > libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.42.0) but it is not installable
> > > libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not installable
> > > libpangomm-1.4-1 (>= 2.27.1) but it is not installable
> > > libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
> > >
> > > > E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Is there a way to find out what is missing and broken?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using apt-get instead of the software center

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

if it still complains about unmet dependencies apt-get can try to fix them with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still get the same error of unmet dependencies. Perhaps I'll have to revert to 14.04.?